# PostgreSQL Error: operator does not exist: name = integer

Tags: sql, postgresql

Getting an operator mismatch error when doing a simple query.  What causes this?

```
dev_db=# `select * from registrants where user=1;`
ERROR:  operator does not exist: name = integer
LINE 1: select * from registrants where user=1;
                                            ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Table definition:

```
dev_db=# \d+ registrants
                              Table "public.registrants"
    Column    |           Type           |     Modifiers      | Storage  | Description
--------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------
 user         | integer                  | not null           | plain    |
 degree       | text                     |                    | extended |
 title        | text                     |                    | extended |
 organization | text                     |                    | extended |
 address      | text                     |                    | extended |
 city         | text                     |                    | extended |

Indexes:
    "registrants_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("user")
Foreign-key constraints:
    "registrants_country_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (country) REFERENCES countries(id)
    "registrants_user_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("user") REFERENCES users(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "class_evaluations" CONSTRAINT "class_evaluations_registrant_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (registrant) REFERENCES registrants("user")

Triggers:
    archive_registrants BEFORE DELETE OR UPDATE ON registrants FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE archive_reg_table()
Has OIDs: no
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the manual, `USER` is a reserved keyword. You must quote it to avoid the syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM registrants WHERE "user" = 1
```

[PostgreSQL Reserved Keyword List](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html)

If you have time to alter the database, change the column name to one which is not a reserved keyword. This will help you avoid future headaches.

Comment: @user2254435: Don't use reserved words as identifiers to begin with.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  This is from a large existing application and not so easy to change.